# Correct Login Leads to 403 Forbidden Error in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am pulling in various logins from my CSV file using the CSV Data Set Config. I am manually able to log in as each user. When I run the script in jMeter, I am able to login as every user except the first (happens with/without the "ignore first line" checked). I get a 403 Forbidden error and the response data says "invalid login."

I don't get why this is happening. Can I get some suggestions, please?

Comment: Show some code and logs, please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to inspect your test plan for any dynamic parameters. Modern web applications widely use them for i.e. [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) or [client-side state management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). If you record your test scenario 2 times and see that each time there is at least one dynamic parameter - you will need to work it around like:

   - HTTP Request #1 - open login page

     - JMeter [Post-Processor(s)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract dynamic parameter(s)
   - HTTP Request #2 - perform login, send credentials along with dynamic parameter(s)

The process is known as "correlation".

You can also consider using an alternative option of recording a JMeter test using cloud-based proxy service, it is capable of exporting tests in "SmartJMX" mode, it means that all dynamic elements will be automatically detected and relevant [Regular Expression Extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) will be added to test plan. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a hidden parameter that I wasn't getting, which was required in order to be able to log in successfully. Once I put that as a parameter in the HTTP request for logging in, it worked. Thank you.